# CSS Font face not working in simple html stactic site

Tags: css

Here is a link http://mprs.proxyrental.net:83/aspnet/index.html

```
    @font-face {
    font-family: 'EurostileNormalRegular';
    src: url('../fonts/eurostile-normal.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/eurostile-normal.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/eurostile-normal.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/eurostile-normal.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/eurostile-normal.svg#EurostileNormalRegular') format('svg');
}

body{ margin:0px;padding:0px; font-family:EurostileNormalRegular; font-size:11px;}
```

I have created a test here the fot working perfect

and link http://mprs.proxyrental.net:83/aspnet/test.html

Comment: Where should it be appeared in the site, sorry but I can't understand, I can't see `@font-face` in your 1st site.

Comment: Your body in that page doesn't have this font, it says: `font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incorrect path in your font declaration:

```
url('EurostileLTStd(1)/eurostileltstd.eot')
```

Should be

```
url('/EurostileLTStd(1)/eurostileltstd.eot')
```

[as explained here](http://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/)

You're also not really including the font in your `body` in your CSS.

Comment: @ConnorGurney: I've noticed a different problem now

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos: yes, I've mentioned the problem you've mentioned in the comments before my edit

Comment: If the path would have been the case, then it would have not worked for the `test.html` too - @MMM

Comment: @MMM , I didn't see it, if it was useful/another bug, why did you delete it then?

Comment: @FrankPresenciaFandos: See Connor's comment

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the font name under body in quotes.

Comment: That makes no difference, quotes are required for fonts with spaces in their names

Answer (score 0):

There is an extra `g` under `@charset "utf-8";` at the top of your `style.css`. Remove it and then check.

Comment: How would that prevent a font from loading?

Comment: But any negligent error, if not required, should be removed weather it protects a font from loading or not. As `@charset "utf-8";` is not a comment, so it may affect font loading. - @MMM